# How to get HTML table cell data using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to extract table cell data using javascript/jquery.

Table cell structure:

```
<select id="id_item_set-0-type" name="item_set-0-type" onchange="get_names_list(this)" required="required">
    <option value="">SELECT</option>
    <option value="GOLD" selected="selected">GOLD</option>
    <option value="SILVER">SILVER</option>
</select>
```

jquery Function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var table_id = document.getElementById('item_grid');
    var rows_len = table_id.rows.length-2;
    for(var i=1; i <= rows_len; i++){
        var e = table_id.rows[i].cells[0].firstChild;
        alert(table_id.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
        var item_type = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    }
});
```

If i use `table_id.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML` i get cell html but i want to get selected option value.
I tried `e.options[e.selectedIndex].text` but it is throwing error `e.selectedIndex is undefined`. How do i get the selected option value.?

Their are actually Two `select tags`

```
<select id="id_item_set-0-name" name="item_set-0-name" required="required">
<option value="">SELECT</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Name1</option>
<option value="2">name2</option>
..............
</select>
```

And i have to extract selected  values of both.
`For example : item_type = "GOLD" and item_name = "name1"`

Their can be any number of rows that i have to iterate. And have to get values of both `item_type` and `item_name`.

Comment: table_id.rows[i].cells[0].children[0].value

Comment: `item type` is first cell and `item_name` is second cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var selected_val= $('#"id_item_set-0-type :selected"').val();
    var selected_text=$('#"id_item_set-0-type :selected"').text();
}
```

Comment: Id can be changed is created dynamically from server side. Not hard coded.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i replace dynamically fetched cell id . What i mean is i have `item_type` cell `id` stored in variable `item_type_id`. Now i want to use that id in `$('#"id_item_set-0-type :selected"').val();`. Now besides string concatenating is their another way??

Answer (score 1):

Why are you confusing select tags with table tags?

All you need is:

```
$('#id_item_set-0-type').find(":selected").text();
```

add it inside your `.ready()` function.

If your ID is dynamically generated at server side and if that is the only select statement you have, use:

```
$('select').find(":selected").text();
```